# How can two files with same name, content, owner, and permissions be different?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, centos-7

I have two identical files (file contents are simply `asd`) with `644` permissions and owned by `root:root`, one created at 19:24 and the other created at 19:25.

The first file was uploaded via SFTP as `root` and the other one was created on the server directly by a sudoer. The files were then moved to the document root with one of them named `index.html`.

If the first file is named `index.html`, I get a 403-response when visiting my website:

> **Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server.

However, if the second file is named `index.html` it is served as expected and I can see `asd` on the page.

---

Result of `ll` when it works:
[image]

Result of `ll` when I get 403 Forbidden:
[image]

I am completely dumbfounded. What is happening here?

Comment: It is not clear which file is uploaded via SFTP and which one is created by "sudoers". I suggest editing the question to reflect that.

Comment: It is probably SELinux. Reset the labels on the objects in the directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files have more attributes than `ls -l` shows. For example, many filesystems have several 'flag' attributes to change the file's behavior (visible in `lsattr`) and many can store arbitrary data in the form of extended attributes (visible in `getfattr`).

Linux is also not limited to just three classes of permissions; a file can have a *list* of users and groups assigned to it – this would be indicated by a plus sign `+` next to standard permissions, and the whole list would be visible in `getfacl`.

But in this case here, the dot `.` next to file permissions indicates that the file has a *security context label* applied to it, which indicates the file's purpose. You should be able to see this parameter in **`ls -Z`** and it's used by "Mandatory Access Control" modules – usually [SELinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) or sometimes SMACK – to enforce limits on which processes can access it *even if* the owner has set them to world-readable.

While SELinux can often automatically apply the correct label to files based on what directory they're created in, this does not work when the file was originally created elsewhere and only later moved into the final location. So if you run `ls -lZ` you'll probably see that the inaccessible file has a completely different label than the rest.

To fix this, you should be able to run **`restorecon`** on the file, which will set the correct context according to installed SELinux policy.

Comment: SELinux was precisely the issue. It had the `user_home_t` context (since it was uploaded there before being moved to the document root) rather than `httpd_sys_content_t`. I didn't have this problem on my previous VPS, so I had probably disabled SELinux there (not sure if a good idea or not).

Answer (score 2):

The dot after the ACLs means that there are extended rights.

`getfacl index.html*` should show the difference...